# Python check proccess still runnig via its name

Tags: python

I want know how can I find if a specific process with a specific name is still running or not ?

```
import multiprocessing
from time import sleep

def proc():
    for i in range(10000):
        sleep(.05)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.process.Process(target=proc, name='name1').start()
    multiprocessing.process.Process(target=proc, name='name2').start()
    multiprocessing.process.Process(target=proc, name='name3').start()
    multiprocessing.process.Process(target=proc, name='name4').start()

    #how i know in here process with name 'name1' is finiehsd or not ?
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.current_process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import multiprocessing
from time import sleep

def proc():
    for i in range(10000):
        sleep(.05)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    list = []
    for i in xrange(4):
        p = multiprocessing.process.Process(target=proc, name='name' + str(i))
        p.start()
        list.append(p)

    # Mainthread check which is still alive and which is not.
    while 1:
        for p in list:
            if not p.is_alive():
                print p.name + " is Done!"
                p.join()
                list.remove(p)
```

This is one solution.